# Can you create resources inside an Azure AD B2C directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

## Hierarchy / Relationships

I'm rather confused about the relationship between Azure AD, subscriptions, resources and Azure AD B2C.

This is how I *think* it's tied together:

- An Azure AD directory (or organization?) can have many subscriptions
- Subscriptions can only be tied to a single directory
- Resources (inside resource groups) can only belong to a single subscription
- You can have up to 20 Azure AD B2C tenants/directories per subscription

This gives the following example hierarchy:

- Azure AD directory (contoso.com)

  - Dev subscription

    - Resource group X

      - Azure AD B2C #1
      - Azure AD B2C #2
  - Prod subscription

    - Resource Group Y

      - Azure AD B2C #3
      - Azure AD B2C #4

Do correct me if I'm wrong, please!

## The really confusing part

In the Azure portal, I have a B2C tenant resource in my AD directory:

[image]

Also, from the menu in the top right corner, I can click 'Switch directory', and see both my AD directory and my B2C directory:

[image]

When I switch to the B2C directory, I get the same left menu that I have in my AD directory:

[image]

Ok.

**So I have a menu option to create a resource, and I can also view resources inside this B2C directory!**

Questions:

1. Can you actually create resources inside a B2C directory? Seems to me that B2C is itself a resource, belonging to a specific subscription and a specific AD directory.
2. If you *can*, when would you – if ever – do it?

I'm thinking this is simply a quirk of the Azure Portal. I don't see how you could create a resource inside a B2C directory using e.g. ARM / Bicep / Terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create resources in B2C tenant. In general resources are created and belong to the subscription, not the tenant. You would have to have the subscription assigned to your B2C tenant but that is not possible.

1. Yes it is a resource, belonging to specific subscription (for billing purposes) and subscription is linked to AAD tenant
2. No, the main goal of B2C is to manage identities. If it would be ever possible it wouldn't work well. Much better idea is to create an additional subscription in your base tenant if you ever need to separate resources (for example for billing purposes).

Comment: You would have to have the subscription assigned to your B2C tenant but that is not possible.

Are you sure this is not possible? I seem to be seeing just that. I have a sub I can only see when im in my b2c directory, and when I click it, it clearly shows its assigned to my b2c directory.

Answer (score 1):

fwiw, nothing in Azure stops you from creating a new subscription (linked to whatever billing account / Microsoft agreement / billing profile you want) and associating it with your B2C tenant.  You can then create resources under that subscription which only lives under that B2C tenant.  This subscription is separate from the subscription in some other tenant from which you created the B2C tenant.

I'm involved in a project where we are considering creating resources for a full stack custom application that would be manifested in a subscription we created in the B2C tenant. But, it's hard to find anyone else talking about taking that approach, so we are wondering if we are going to hit any unexpected hurdles, or if there is a clear reason not to do this that we just aren't seeing (security or otherwise).